# Emulating "nosetests -w working-dir" behavior using py.test

Tags: python, testing, pytest, nose

I am porting a series of tests from `nosetests` + `python unittest` to `py.test`. I was pleasantly surprised to learn that `py.test` supports python `unittests` and running existing tests with `py.test` is just as easy as calling `py.test` instead of `nosetests` on the command line. However I am having problems with specifying the [working directory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) for the tests. They are not in the root project dir but in a subdir. Currently the tests are run like this:

```
$ nosetests -w test-dir/ tests.py
```

which changes the current working directory to `test-dir` and run all the tests in `tests.py`. However when I use `py.test`

```
$ py.test test-dir/tests.py
```

all the tests in `tests.py` are run but the current working directory is not changed to `test-dir`. Most tests assume that the working directory is `test-dir` and try to open and read files from it which obviously fails.

So my question is how to change the current working directory for all tests when using `py.test`.

The are a lot of tests and I don't want to invest the time to fix them all and make them work regardless of the cwd.

Yes, I can simply do `cd test-dir; py.test tests.py` but I am used to working from the project root directory and don't want to cd every time I want to run a test.

Here is some code that may give you better idea what I am trying to achieve:

content of `tests.py`:

```
import unittest
class MyProjectTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_something(self):
      with open('testing-info.txt', 'r') as f:
          test something with f
```

directory layout:

```
my-project/
   test-dir/
       tests.py
       testing-info.txt
```

And then when I try to run the tests:

```
$ pwd
my-project
$ nosetests -w test-dir tests.py
# all is fine
$ py.test ttest-dir/tests.py
# tests fail because they cannot open testing-info.txt
```

Comment: You should need to change directory, I generally run tests in `/tests` from the project root using py.test. Could you give a clearer example of the specific problem you're facing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited the question providing a better explanation what I want to do.

Comment: Have you consider making the tests look for resources relative to themselves, rather than to the test directory? This will make your tests more explicit beyond the working directory issue.

Comment: Yeah, that's totally doable. But it's going to require some time ( it's a big project there are hundreds of tests ). And I was hoping for a quick fix. I mean I was very impressed by the fact that only by changing `nosetests` to `py.tests` all the tests were run so I though there must be a way to quickly fix the current working dir issue too.

Comment: For example: https://github.com/textbook/aslack/blob/master/setup.py#L14

Comment: Have you read http://pytest.org/latest/customize.html?

Comment: I feel like this discussion is going in the wrong way. I am just asking if `py.test` offers an alternative to `nosetests -w` functionality and if yes then what is the command line argument that I need to give to `py.test`.

Comment: Same question; have you tried *configuring it, according to the documentation?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the best I could come up with:

```
# content of conftest.py
import pytest
import os

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("-W", action="store", default=".",
        help="Change current working dir before running the collected tests.")

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    os.chdir(session.config.getoption('W'))
```

And then when running the tests

```
$ py.test -W test-dir test-dir/tests.py
```

It's not clean but it will do the trick until I fix all the tests.